# Python - Keep command window open to see results

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a text file (test.txt) that contains

```
text1 text2 text text text
```

Below is my code:

```
import codecs
BOM = codecs.BOM_UTF8.decode('utf8')
name = (raw_input("Please enter the name of the file: "))

with codecs.open(name, encoding='utf-8') as f:
    words=[]            #define words here
    for line in f:
        line = line.lstrip(BOM)
        words.extend(line.split())        #append words from each line to words  

if len(words) > 2:
    print 'There are more than two words'
    firstrow = words[:2]
    print firstrow                #indentation problem here
elif len(words) <2:                    #use if
    print 'There are under 2 words, no words will be shown'

raw_input("Press return to close this window...")
```

When I run the .py file, I want to keep the command window open so I can see all the prints, but for some reason it closes right away, when I run this in shell it works. For some reasoning the raw_input is not working like it normally has for me. Its my 2nd day at python so I am still a newbie!

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: chances are you have an error somewhere before the raw input ...

Answer (score 0):

Newbie question, newbie answer!!

I didnt have my text file in the directory of my .py only in my shell path which is why it was working there.

Answer (score 0):

You should put at least the file reading code in a try/except block, so you can see what errors occur;

```
import codecs

BOM = codecs.BOM_UTF8.decode('utf8')
name = raw_input("Please enter the name of the file: ")

try:
  with codecs.open(name, encoding='utf-8') as f:
    words=[]            #define words here
    for line in f:
        line = line.lstrip(BOM)
        words.extend(line.split())
except Exception as details:
  print "Unexpected error:", details
  raw_input("Press return to close this window...")
  exit(1)

if len(words) > 2:
    print 'There are more than two words'
    firstrow = words[:2]
    print firstrow
elif len(words) <2:                    #use if
    print 'There are under 2 words, no words will be shown'

raw_input("Press return to close this window...")
```

If I try this with a nonexisting filename:

```
Please enter the name of the file: bla
Unexpected error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'bla'
Press return to close this window...
```